# Scraping a website in Python with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape the data from this website with Selenium, in Python:

https://www.caffeineinformer.com/the-caffeine-database

This is the code I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.caffeineinformer.com/the-caffeine-database"

cService = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path = 'C:/Users/Username/Downloads/chromedriver-win32/chromedriver-win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = cService)
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
brand = driver.find_element("xpath",'//div[@class="dataTable-table"]//tbody/tr/td[2]')
```

But I am not able to locate the brand names, or indeed, any of the columns.

The data I want is under the 'All' tab, but that tab is selected by default and the tab button is active in the HTML, so I am not sure if I should be checking for it. But the rest of the data is not accessible either.
Can anybody help with where I am going wrong?

Comment: The issue you have is that you are searching in the class `dataTable-table` which is the header labels of the table. What you should be searching to get the table contents would be `dataTable-container`. So replacing that in your find_element call would render 8.46 (the fl. oz. of 28 Black Energy Drink). If there still is nothing rendered, you may want to wait for the page to load before you try finding any page elements by using something like `time.sleep`

Answer (score 0):

Xpath wrote by you is wrong, and should traverse the list to get the brand.The right code is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.caffeineinformer.com/the-caffeine-database"
server = Service(executable_path='/webdriver/chromedriver_windows_115.exe')
driver = Chrome(service=server)
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@class="dataTable-table" and @id="caffeinedb"]/tbody//tr')
brand_list = []
for row in rows:
    brand = row.find_element(By.XPATH, './td/a').text
    brand_list.append(brand)
print(brand_list)
```

[image]